# How to print lines of a text file entered earlier in the program

Tags: java, text-files, inputstream, filereader, fileoutputstream

I have an assignment due to create a program that lets the user enter 5 Strings, saves them to a text file and then outputs the lines of the text file, but after the Strings are entered the program just prints "null".

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WriteLines
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    String k;
    String fileName = "Input.txt";
    String aLine;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Input.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a String of text: ");
        k=sc.nextLine();
        pw.println(k);
    }
    pw.close();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bl = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while((aLine = bl.readLine()) !=null);
    {
        System.out.println(aLine);
    }

    bl.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `while` loop, at the end you can see `;` which means something like this:

```
while ((aLine = bl.readLine()) != null) {
    ;
}
{
    System.out.println(aLine);
}
```

---

The loop runs until `aLine == null`, so printing `aLine` after the loop has ended prints `null`. Removing this `;` character will cause your code to work.